# Why is the print function not running at the right time?

Tags: python, printing

Here is my code:

```
import time as t

print('hello', end=' ')
t.sleep(1)
print('hello', end=' ')
t.sleep(1)
print('hello', end=' ')
t.sleep(1)
```

My problem is that all the print commands are executed after the sleep commands, and that's not my intended output.

Comment: Where are you printing to? I cannot reproduce, but there is a buffer for `stdout` and likely it's not getting flushed.

Comment: I mean, have you directed stdout somewhere? This should print fine to a console.

Comment: Do you mean that it takes three seconds then prints hello three times? Because it printed hello three times with a one second break between for me

Comment: @JonathanDyke It printed all at the end for me.

Comment: I just ran it in a jupyter notebook as I had one open I don't know if that changed anything

Comment: There is an optional `flush` parameter to `print()` in Python 3. If you add `flush=True`, `print` should print immediately.

Comment: Closely related: [How to flush output of print function?](//stackoverflow.com/q/230751)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of output buffering. The buffer isn't flushed until a newline is printed. Since you used `end=' '`, there's no newline after each word, so the buffer isn't flushed until the script ends.

You can use the `flush=True` option to force it to flush immediately.

```
import time as t
import sys

print('hello', end=' ', flush=True)
t.sleep(1)
print('hello', end=' ', flush=True)
t.sleep(1)
print('hello', end=' ', flush=True)
t.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This won't give the desired behaviour though, I don't think. I can get the output fine and on a single line being sequentially built

Comment: @ChristianDean Just discovered that myself, was about to edit

Comment: Gotcha @Barmar.

Comment: print('hello\n', end=' ') why this one work correct? what does new line work in print??

Comment: Because you're writing a newline to the output buffer @mohamadmahdireisi, causing it to be flushed.

Comment: @mohamadmahdireisi When a newline is printed, the buffer is flushed. It doesn't matter whether the newline is in the data, or it's printed automatically.

Comment: To be precise: it's not necessarily a newline (`\n`) lacking. If you want to overwrite the same line, a carriage return (`\r`) is sufficient for flushing the buffer, too.